# How to host multiple webpages under the same name eg. example.io on a localhost such that different users are shown different pages?

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I have 50 users named as User1....User50 and 50 html pages named Page1....Page50 and I want to have a common domain name say example.io such that if User1 types example.io in the browser he is redirected to Page1, if User2 types example.io in the browser he is redirected to Page2 and so on. Is there a way out for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can learn more about [ask] a question to better support the folks who can help you with your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can show different content with PHP base of the user data. But without anything else, I don't see how you will recognize User1 and User2 unless you have login page. 
Base of the user login data then you can add conditions to redirect/show the different HTML pages